# How to share code between a job and a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some functionality in a controller that I **also** want in a background job (ActiveJob). If the code was all equal in both, to avoid code duplication, I guess the proper way would be to move the shared functionality to the job, and execute the job (`perform_now`) from the controller?

But what if the code is not all equal, where i only need some of the methods in both, what would be the proper way to tho this? Would it be to move the shared code to

- public class methods in the job class, and call these from the controller?
- libs? (Or are they too general?)
- concerns?
- helpers?

What would be the proper way to share methods between a job and a controller? How do you guys do this?

Comment: You can use a so-called service object under the "app/services" folder. Minimizing the number of responsibilities you can have an easily testeable Ruby class which you can use from anywhere (controllers, jobs, helpers, models, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both concerns and helpers are just modules. And thus can both be used for parallel inheritance.

Helpers have a specific role in Rails which is code-sharing between the view and controller, they are also automatically included into every controller which makes them a bad choice in this case. Helpers are the sweaty armpits of a Rails app and are best used for HTML generation or other view concerns.

"concerns" is really just a Rails convention which adds the folders `app/controller/concerns` and `app/models/concerns` to the auto-loading root directories. Unlike helpers they are not automatically included in your controller. If you want to use module mixins this would probably be a good place.

If the functionality is a simple set of methods this could be a good choice.
There are a handful of great uses of modules like Enumerable that really provide a set of behaviors to a wide array of classes but most modules tend to be proverbial junk drawers.

> Splitting things up doesn’t make things easier — it only means I can
>   pretend that my files are small and that my main module doesn’t
>   introduce that many methods. Even though I wrote the code, I’m
>   constantly confused about which file holds what method. If anything,
>   splitting out files in this way makes my job as a maintainer harder.
>   - [Scheems](https://blog.codeship.com/good-module-bad-module/)

Sebastian Palma touched on one solution to this problem - *Service Objects*. Jobs are actually just a more advanced type of service object but you can compose a service object that encapsulates the functionality shared between the controller and job if the functionality warrants it.

> public class methods in the job class, and call these from the
>   controller?

**Hell no.** Jobs should just do one job and do it well. Create more jobs/service objects if needed. Don't turn a good single purpose object into a junk drawer.

#### Summary

What kind of objects you create matters just as much as where you place them. There is no quick and easy answer - you need to look carefully at what the code does:

- Is it a generic behavior that can augment multiple classes? Module mixin and / or macro pattern.
- Does it take some sort of input and do a unit of work? Service object/job.
- Does it do HTTP calls or in some other way touch the application boundary? Client object.
- Does it encapsulate some sort of business logic with rules that act upon it? Model/virtual model.